An element with position set to fixed in CSS extends beyond the bottom of the browser
An element with position: fixed; and bottom: 0; set extends beyond the bottom of the browser.
Setting height: 100%; and overflow: auto; for html and body solves the problem, but is there any other way?
Due to certain circumstances, meta tags cannot be changed.
For some reason the snippet doesn't cause the problem.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>An element with position: fixed; bottom: 0; set extends beyond the bottom of the browser</title>
  <style>
    /* Adding the following will fix the issue */
    /*
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    */
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .space {
      height: 1000px;
    }
    .cont {
      height: 200px;
      /* Removing the negative margins solves the problem */
      margin: 0 -1rem;
      background: #ccc;
    }
    .fixed {
      position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 3rem;
      background-color: #84cc16;
      color: #fff;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="space"></div>
  <div class="cont">contents</div>
  <div class="fixed">fixed</div>
</body>
</html>





I really didn't get what you are trying to say but when I checked the output of the code, I noticed that it has overlfow-x due to margin: 0 -1rem; set to .cont. When I removed it, it worked fine.

What is "an element"? Please revise to be more specific.
